# JS применение метода foreach у массива

Tags: javascript

```js
class Unit {
  constructor() {
    this.item = [new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3)]
  }
}
let forFunc = function(array) {
  array.forEach(it => console.log(it))
}

let unit = new Unit(1, 2);
console.log(forFunc(unit.item));
```

Вывод:

```
Item { id: 1 }Item { id: 2 }Item { id: 3 }undefined
```

Вопрос:

Откуда берется undefined при чем это только по foreach, если взять join или фильтр то все норм

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `forFunc` ничего не возвращает:

```js
function Item(id) {
  this.id = id;
}

class Unit {
  constructor() {
    this.item = [new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3)]
  }
}
let forFunc = function(array) {
  array.forEach(it => console.log(it))
}

let unit = new Unit(1, 2);
forFunc(unit.item);
```

Comment: Вопрос все таки, как на проме люди работают используют
function Item(id) {
  this.id = id;
}
или через class?